# Finding the size of newly replaced array whose N is now reduced

Tags: c, arrays

i want to find the size of a new array that's size is now reduced. But when i write the size function for new replaced array, it doesn't return the exact value it only returns size to n2 = 1 when it should be size n2 = 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void dupsRemove (int *arr, int n)
{
int i,newA[10],n2;
 for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  if (arr[i] == arr[i+1])
   {
      i++;
    }
     printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}
n2 = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
printf("\n %d",n2);

}
int main()
{
int arr[]={1,3,3,2,5},i,j;
int n= *(&arr + 1) - arr;
dupsRemove(arr,n);
}
```

Comment: pointer arithmetic return the distance between elements. Multiply by sizeof elements to get the actual size

Comment: @Afrida Anzum Aesha Do you want to remove adjacent equal elements?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow yah but i want to use recursion here, that's why i want the new size of n. I can find the n by n-- . But can't I find that new n using the sizeof function?

Comment: @AfridaAnzumAesha Do you want to write a recursive function that removes duplicates?

Comment: @AfridaAnzumAesha It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yah i want to write recursive function that removes duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you pass the array into any function in C, the variable gets typecasted into one defined in the prototype of the function.

Inside the scope of dupsRemove(int *arr, int n), arr is of type (int *) whose size is given as sizeof(arr) = 8 or 4 depending on whether you are using a 64 bit or a 32 bit compiler respectively.

The only option to have the size of the array in function scope is to send the size of the array as an argument and change it accordingly when you modify the array.